# How to output query data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been trying all day, looked at references, looked at other questions similar to mine, nothing seems to be working.

PROBLEM: I can't output query data.

This is my most recent iteration of the code:

```
try {
    $link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users_db', 'root', '56235623');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
$sql = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM users');
$sql->execute();

$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.$value;
}
```

Here is the output:

> > Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\Includes\cn.php on line 23
> >     0Array
> >     Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\Includes\cn.php on line 23
> >     1Array
> >     Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\Includes\cn.php on line 23
> >     2Array
> >     Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\Includes\cn.php on line 23
> >     3Array

Comment: check here.http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-querying-data-from-mysql-table/

Comment: according to your error message, the $value is array, which you just can't echo: foreach ($result as $key=>$value){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchAll` returns a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension is the rows, the second dimension is the columns. So you need nested loops:

```
foreach ($result as $i => $row) {
    echo "Row: $i\n";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key: $value; ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$value` is array, change to:

```
foreach ($result as $key=>$value){
    echo $key;
    //check what $value contains
    print_r($value);
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like your notice is suggesting, you're trying to convert an array to string.
If you just want to print the content of the `$result` variable, you can use:

```
var_dump($result);
```

or

```
print_r($result);
```

If you want to use the `foreach` to print each value in your own format:

```
foreach ($result as $key=>$values){
    echo "Key: " , $key, " Values:", implode(", ", $values), "<br />";
}
```

The `implode` method will concatenate all the values in the array using ", " as a glue element.

If you want to iterate through your `$values` array, you should look at Barmar's answer.